# Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' due to java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException in Grails

Tags: java, maven, grails, grails-2.2

I had used Grails-2.2.0, JDK-1.7.0 for Grails Application Development along with Maven for dependency management. Application runs fine but receives following error when I deploy grails application war build from Maven on Tomcat 7.0:

```
`SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:591)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5641)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1015)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:991)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1127)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:2020)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.getParameterTypes(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericParameterTypes(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.FeatureDescriptor.getParameterTypes(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.setMethod(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl$15.run(MetaClassImpl.java:2924)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.addProperties(MetaClassImpl.java:2922)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.initialize(MetaClassImpl.java:2905)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.initialize(ExpandoMetaClass.java:312)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:164)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:180)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.<init>(ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:35)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.createClassMetaClassGetPropertySite(AbstractCallSite.java:304)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.createGetPropertySite(AbstractCallSite.java:258)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.acceptGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:245)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:237)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.cfg.ConfigurationHelper.loadConfigFromClasspath(ConfigurationHelper.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.getConfig(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:296)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.setPluginFilter(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:185)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.<init>(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:169)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 26 more`
```

And my pom.xml for Maven build is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MyApp</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>grails-app</packaging>
  <properties>
    <grails.version>2.2.0</grails.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder</groupId>
        <artifactId>http-builder</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-resolver</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-resolver</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
      <artifactId>grails-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>${grails.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
        <artifactId>grails-plugin-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${grails.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>${grails.version}</version>
        <type>zip</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>${grails.version}</version>
        <type>zip</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
        <type>zip</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>resources</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
        <type>zip</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>database-migration</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <type>zip</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <type>zip</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>csv</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.1</version>
        <type>zip</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connectorj</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.22.1</version>
        <type>zip</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mnode.ical4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>ical4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>                
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement />
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
             <skip>true</skip>
           </configuration>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <id>surefire-it</id>
               <phase>integration-test</phase>
               <goals>
                 <goal>test</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                 <skip>false</skip>
               </configuration>
             </execution>
           </executions>
         </plugin>        
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <filesets>
                <fileset>
                    <directory>plugins</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*</include>
                    </includes>
                    <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                </fileset>
            </filesets>
         </configuration>
      </plugin> 
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
        <artifactId>grails-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${grails.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <fork>true</fork>
        </configuration>        
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>grails</id>
        <name>grails</name>
        <url>http://repo.grails.org/grails/core</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>grails-plugins</id>
        <name>grails-plugins</name>
        <url>http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>grails-plugins1</id>
        <name>grails-plugins1</name>
        <url>https://grails.org/plugins</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2</id>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
      <profiles>
        <profile>
          <id>tools</id>
          <activation>
            <property>
              <name>java.vendor</name>
              <value>Sun Microsystems Inc.</value>
            </property>
          </activation>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
              <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
              <version>${java.version}</version>
              <scope>system</scope>
              <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </profile>
      </profiles>
  </project>
```

What am I doing wrong? I had included all dependencies of project in pom.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had updated my pom.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MyApp</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
  <packaging>grails-app</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>A custom grails project</name>
  <description>A custom grails project</description>
  <url>http://www.myorganization.org</url>

  <properties>
    <grails.version>2.2.0</grails.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
      <artifactId>grails-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>${grails.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
        <artifactId>grails-plugin-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${grails.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>    

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>${grails.version}</version>
        <type>zip</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>${grails.version}</version>
        <type>zip</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
        <type>zip</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>resources</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
        <type>zip</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>database-migration</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <type>zip</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <type>zip</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connectorj</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.22.1</version>
        <type>zip</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mnode.ical4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>ical4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement />

    <plugins>
        <!-- Disables the Maven surefire plugin for Grails applications, as we have our own test runner -->
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
             <skip>true</skip>
           </configuration>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <id>surefire-it</id>
               <phase>integration-test</phase>
               <goals>
                 <goal>test</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                 <skip>false</skip>
               </configuration>
             </execution>
           </executions>
         </plugin>        
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <filesets>
                <fileset>
                    <directory>plugins</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*</include>
                    </includes>
                    <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                </fileset>
            </filesets>
         </configuration>
      </plugin> 

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
        <artifactId>grails-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${grails.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <fork></fork>
        </configuration>        
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>grails</id>
      <name>grails</name>
      <url>http://repo.grails.org/grails/core</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>grails-plugins</id>
      <name>grails-plugins</name>
      <url>http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins</url>
    </repository>
    <!-- uncomment the following snapshot repository if you want to use snapshot versions of the grails-maven-plugin -->
    <!--
    <repository>
      <id>grails-plugins-snapshots</id>
      <name>grails-maven-plugins</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    -->
  </repositories>

<!-- uncomment the following snapshot repository if you want to use snapshot versions of the grails-maven-plugin -->
<!--
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>grails-maven-plugins</id>
      <name>grails-maven-plugins</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
-->

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>tools</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>java.vendor</name>
          <value>Sun Microsystems Inc.</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
          <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
          <version>${java.version}</version>
          <scope>system</scope>
          <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

And it worked when I execute `mvn pakage` command along with `-Dgrails.env=production` as argument